# Add a badge for closing questions

Tags: discussion, badges

I think by closing a question, we are keeping the site *clean*.

So, I propose to recognize people who close questions with a badge.

I'm surprised that there isn't one currently.

Wanted to know, if anyone feels the same.

Comment: This could be called "The Terminator" badge. But I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Related MSE: [Badge for Closing Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25053/badge-for-closing-question) (and make sure to look at the linked questions there too).

Comment: How do we stop morons from closing answerable questions that they apparently don't understand?

Answer (score 21):

We only add badges for behavior we want to encourage. We've already seen people just rush to close questions to reduce the size of the review queue. I can only imagine what will happen if we start to give out badges for it.

Comment: any suggestions on how I could delete my useless question and keep this site *clean*? ;)

Comment: There is no need for that. You asked a question that now doesn't need to be asked again. So let's keep it around.

Comment: If not badges, then hats surely? =D

Answer (score 3):

While we don't have badges for closing questions, we have badges per review queue that would cover this and not encourage closure just for the sake of a badge.

[image]